# Is it possible to change the background colour of a CMFCEditBrowseCtrl control?

Tags: mfc

VS2015 Dialog MFC

I have several **CMFCEditBrowseCtrl** implemented on my dialog with custom behavior for the **browse** button:

[image: CMFCEditBrowseCtrl dialog]

Is it possible to conditionally set the **background** of the **edit** part of the control to **red** at run time? And when required set the background of the edit back to the **default**?

Thank you.

**Update**
I see that the control is derived from **CEdit**, so I am going to give this a try:

[MFC: Changing the colour of CEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218035/mfc-changing-the-colour-of-cedit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from above [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218052/4603670) is in the right direction, however it is not implemented correctly. `CtlColor` should return a brush handle. It also needs to set text background color with `CDC::SetBkColor`

```
class cmfc_edit : public CMFCEditBrowseCtrl
{
public:
    COLORREF bkcolor;
    CBrush brush;

    void setBrushColor(COLORREF clr)
    {
        bkcolor = clr;
        brush.DeleteObject();
        brush.CreateSolidBrush(clr);
    }

    HBRUSH CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT)
    {
        if (!brush.GetSafeHandle())
            return GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW);
        pDC->SetBkColor(bkcolor);
        return brush;
    }

    //optional, change color on focus change
    void OnSetFocus(CWnd* w)
    {
        setBrushColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
        CMFCEditBrowseCtrl::OnSetFocus(w);
    }

    void OnKillFocus(CWnd* w)
    {
        setBrushColor(RGB(255, 255, 255));
        CMFCEditBrowseCtrl::OnKillFocus(w);
    }

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(cmfc_edit, CMFCEditBrowseCtrl)
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()

    //optional
    ON_WM_SETFOCUS()
    ON_WM_KILLFOCUS()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

usage:

```
mfc_edit.setBrushColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks. I get you. How do we ensure that in `OnKillFocus` it reverts back to the "default" background colour? IE: if they are using WindowsBlinds ... the background might not be white.

Comment: I guess I should have put `GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW)` for default color in `OnKillFocus`