# how to transparent the background of edit box in mfc vc++?

Tags: winapi, mfc

In this there is one static control text in blue background and edit box has text. Now I want to transparent the background of edit box. I am new in mfc vc++. I am trying to transparent the background of edit box.but till now I am not getting expected result.

[image]

```
if ( pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_editbox)//
{
    pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 255, 0));
pDC->SetBkColor(TRANSPARENT);
pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
return (HBRUSH)::GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
 }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this, but anyway: why would you want a transparent edit control??

Comment: Hello,
there is another static control is behind this in green color background.So I just want to display only text on screen not its background

Comment: Maybe you should [edit] your question and add a picture of what you want vs what you get.

Comment: Don't try to make your edit control transparent, but rather change it's background color as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218035/mfc-changing-the-colour-of-cedit

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I have added the image .Please help if you can.I am just got stuck in this issue from last few weeks.

Comment: In the link you suggested what is the color assigned to  
    " m_brMyEditBk "

Comment: It should obviously be the same color as your blue background. That's up to you.

Comment: @Jabberwocky : Sir it dosen't solve my problem .because at last I have to play a video in static control window.So If I change it to particular color the problems will remains the same.

Comment: Consider this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16296246/898348.

Comment: OK, different story. You probably can't do it.. But from the UI perspective a transparent edit control over a video doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: ok.thank you for your time