# Is it possible to "transparent" the background of "edit box" in mfc vc++?

Tags: winapi, mfc

Is it possible to  "transparent" the background of "edit box" in mfc vc++.
I am trying different methods but not able to do that.

Comment: What methods have you tried?

Comment: @Schmocken see his previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179927/how-to-transparent-the-background-of-edit-box-in-mfc-vc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to transparent the background of edit box in mfc vc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179927/how-to-transparent-the-background-of-edit-box-in-mfc-vc)

Comment: I have used  ONCTLCOLOR function and also try to use OnErasebackground function .but not able to  getting the transparent background color for edit box

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You have to create the class derived from `CEdit` and implement your own `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT` handler just like this:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTransparentEdit, CEdit)
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

class CTransparentEdit : public CEdit
{
  ....
  CBrush   m_brBkgnd;
  afx_msg HBRUSH CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor)
  {
    m_brBkgnd.DeleteObject();
    m_brBkgnd.CreateStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    return (HBRUSH)m_brBkgnd;
  }
}
```